# Python pip: how to install with version indicator and specified string?

Tags: pip

Take PyTorch for example.

In its [index page](https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch/) many different versions of a same release are showed:

- 2.0.0+cpu
- 2.0.0
- 2.0.0+cu117
- 2.0.0+cu118
- 2.0.0+rocm5.3

What should I do if I want to `pip install torch>=1.13.0` and specify the `cpu` package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
pip install torch>=1.13.0+cpu -f the url is too long to write here
```

url : https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch/stable.html

Comment: Your answer is tested and works! By the way, PyTorch now uses `--index-url` instead of `-f`.